# Invalid name argument in Octave ztest

Tags: matlab, statistics, octave

I am trying to make a `Z-test` in Octave, but I have a weird error.

This is my code:

```
A =[ 7 7 4 5 9 9
     4 12 8 1 8 7
     3 13 2 1 17 7
     12 5 6 2 1 13
     14 10 2 4 9 11
     3 5 12 6 10 7 ];

x = A(:)';
n = length(x);
fprintf(' Volume %d \n',n)
med = mean(x);
fprintf(' Sample mean %f\n',med)
sigma = 5;
m0 = 9;

type = -1; %left tailed test

alpha1 = 0.05; %significance level
alpha2 = 0.01;

fprintf('\n')
fprintf('SIGNIFICANCE LEVEL %f:\n',alpha1)
[h1, p1, ci1, zstat1] = ztest(x, m0, sigma, alpha1, type);
```

And the error is:

```
error: Invalid Name argument.
error: called from
    ztest at line 70 column 9
    Pb1a at line 26 column 23
```

I'd like to know why this happens. Hope it is not because I am using Octave instead of Matlab. Actually that is...it works in MATLAB Online.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty explanatory: the syntax you are using (five numeric arguments) is not supported by Octave. In fact, in Matlab that syntax is not documented either, and seems to be supported only for backward compatibility, as can be seen in `ztest` source code:

> ```
> if nargin>=4 <p>
>    if isnumeric(varargin{1})
>        % Old syntax
>        %   ZTEST(X,M,SIGMA,ALPHA,TAIL,DIM)
> [...]
> ```

The solution is to use the syntax officially supported by both [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ztest.html) and [Octave](https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/ztest.html), with arguments beyond the third specified as *parameter, value* pairs:

```
[h1, p1, ci1, zstat1] = ztest(x, m0, sigma, 'alpha', alpha1, 'tail', 'left');
```

Comment: Thanks! The documentation from octave was not explained so detailed